# I have this 3 clustering algorithms and I want to figure out which algorithm has the best algorithm for clustering

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means, hierarchical-bayesian, dbscan

I'm new with clustering. I have this 3 algorithms and I want to figure out which algorithm has the best algorithm for clustering. I posted an image below, to show my clusters. I am confused on how to distinguish which one has the best clustering. Is it DBSCAN because there's 8 clusters? Compared to k-means, which has 3 clusters?

Kmeans

[image: KMeans]

DBSCAN

[image: DBSCAN]

Hierarchical

[image: Hierarchial]

Comment: In the absence of ground truth, the "best clustering" is effectively a "*how long is a piece of string*" question. Clustering first and foremost in an explanatory data technique. If the segmentation suggested is nonsensical, then tautologically that clustering is useless ("bad").

Answer (score 0):

None of them is good.

They are all **severely flawed** in one way or another.

This shows once more that you must not treat clustering as a black box. You need to know what you want to achieve, then process the data appropriately, then cluster. In this data, in your visualization, I would argue that there is only 1 cluster, containing everything. No need for an algorithm then.

Comment: The estimable @Anony-Mousse is I think being sarcastic as a way to provoke learning.  You should go back to the beginning:  why do people perform cluster analysis?  What criteria have others put forth for "good" solutions?  In addition, I recommend labeling the axes of your graphs.

Comment: No, they are all **really bad results**. k-means failed because of scaling, DBSCAN failed because the y axis resolution is too low (discrete data, this will also be problematic for k-means), and the last one just managed to identify duplicate data points. Useless results. And probably, this is **because the data set does *not* have clusters**!